# Q: how can I add a javascript variable to yql query

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, variables, yql

I have a problem. I don't know how can I assign a javascript variable to the existing yql query.

Here is the part of my code:

```
var xxxyyyzzz = 'put_this_variable_to_the_yql_query';

$.getJSON(
  'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?callback=?',
  {
    q: 'select * from html where url="http://address.com/index.php?item=xxxyyyzzz" and xpath="/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody"',
    format: 'json'
  },
  function(data) {
```

I hope somebody could help for me. Many thanks.

Comment: It's not clear where in your yql query you want the variable to appear.

Comment: at the end of the url variable you see xxxyyyzzz. I would like to replace xxxyyyzzz with the text 'put_this_variable_to_the_yql_query'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xxxyyyzzz = encodeURIComponent(xxxyyyzzz);
q: 'select * from html where url="http://address.com/index.php?item=' + xxxyyyzzz + '" and xpath="/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody"',
```

Comment: thank you for the helping. encodeURIComponent I not need now, but thanks anyway!